# Load database files and save them in a folder using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to retrive database files and save each file as a text file with the same file names like database. I have 500 files in database I want to save all of them in my local machine.

I tried below but it is not working. Can anyone modify or edit the below code..

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int i = 0;
        string sql = null;

        connetionString = "Data Source=edevsql2k5-01;Initial Catalog=AIFSOnBase;Integrated Security=True";
        sql = "SELECT vbscript FROM hsi.vbscripttable WHERE vbscriptnum=101";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\VBScriptFiles");

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            adapter.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }

    }



    }
}
```

Comment: Any error messages? You're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: what is result of this code? what is problem in it?

Comment: Your code seems lacking of any attempt to write something inside a file, it just reads the contents of field `vbscript`. What is the content of the field `vbscript`? Do you have a name for the file stored somewhere in your table `vbscripttable` ?

Comment: I am not getting any error message, the above code is working fine. I just want to add the code to save all the vbscript files in my local machine.

Comment: Just can any one provide me the code to save the files in a table to a local machine so that I will add that code to complete my work.